# Authentication Tokens in Blazor Server

Tags: authentication, token, blazor, server-side

I have an ASP.net core WEB API that I have secured using a local user account (used the WASM blazor template to create it).  I can successfully authenticate and call the webapi using the WASM client.

I have a separate Server side Blazor app that attempts to call this WebAPI which again has been secured using a local user account and the same identity database).

In the wasm (webapi) app, I configure security as follows:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                              builder =>
                              {
                                  builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44339");
                              });
        });

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
```

In the server side app, I configure security as follows:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => { options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;  }) 
                        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, 
               RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
        services.AddHttpClient();
```

In the server side app, I then try to get tokens in the _Host.cshtml file so that I can add these to the client header, but they always come back null.

```
        AccessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token"),
        RefreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("refresh_token")
```

I'm a complete newbie on this security side, so appreciate I may have this completely wrong.  Could anyone give me a pointer as to whether I'm doing the wrong thing, or if there's something else I need to do to get these tokens?

Many thanks in advance
Gordon